# How I can move a directory to a other directory in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, directory, move

i want to move a folder from

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/sync//
```

to the android app sandbox

```
file:///data/data/de.tara.SyncMobile/files/files/sync//
```

For this i write a function. I use for help this links:

https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-system-api-20120417/

https://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/file/filesystem/

**Here i my code:**

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0,requestFileSystemSuccess,requestFileSystemError);

function requestFileSystemSuccess(fs)
            {
                console.log("Master.js:requestFileSystemSuccess");

                var syncDir = fs.root.getDirectory("sync",{});
                var syncSandboxDir = fs.root.getDirectory("",{});

                //how i can move the sync directory to the sanbox path????


            }
```

Comment: The Filesystem API (as opposed to the [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)) never took off and is dead; it was never broadly implemented and is actively being removed from those browsers that *did* implement it. You can't manipulate directories from browser-based JavaScript. As it says in the [current version of the linked spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/): **"Work on this document has been discontinued and it should not be referenced or used as a basis for implementation."** *(their emphasis)*

Comment: mhh ok ...what is a other way?

Comment: As I said in my comment above: *"You can't manipulate directories from browser-based JavaScript."*